# AssertionError at /api/v1/companies/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Class CompanySerializers missing "Meta.model" attribute**
I have been making an API using Django Rest Api Framework and it showing the above error whenever I run my app.

My Serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Company

# Create Serializers here


class CompanySerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model: Company
        fields = "__all__"
```

My model.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
#Creating Company model
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    about = models.TextField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length= 100, choices=
                            (('IT','IT'), ('Non IT', 'Non_IT'), ('Mobiles_phones', 'Mobiles_phones'))) 
    added_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from api.models import Company  
from api.serializers import CompanySerializers 
# Create your views here.
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializers
```

I have tried everything and couldn't able to resolve it. Kindly please someone look into this it will quite helpful.

Comment: Typo: `model: Company` must be `model = Company`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
class Meta:
    model: Company
    fields = "__all__"
```

which is a class with a `fields` attribute and an annotation that would specify an attribute `model` to be of type `Company`.

You'd need

```
class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = "__all__"
```

so there's a class with two attributes, `model` and `fields`.

IOW, a single-character typo: `:` should be `=`.

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks for the help